# Send SMS to numbers stored in postgres database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, twilio, sms

I currently have a django app which stores phone numbers in a postgres database. I am looking to send sms (via twilio, or whatever will work) to each of the numbers in the database, as they are added via the django webapp. I'm using pgadmin to monitor the database and it's all hosted on my localhost as of now, do I need to deploy the webapp and database to get twilio working with postgres?

I can't seem to find any clear explanation as to how I can send the messages to the numbers stored as records in my postgres database, any help would be awesome!

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import re
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

# def phone_regex(val):
#     reg = re.compile('^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')
#     if not reg.match(val):
#         raise ValidationError('Phone number must be entered in the format: +999999999. Up to 15 digits allowed.')

# Create your models here.
class Todo(models.Model):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(
        regex= r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
        message= ("Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed."),
        code='invalid_regex',
    )
    content = models.CharField(max_length=17, validators=[phone_regex], blank=False) # validators should be a list
    # content = models.TextField()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
# import pymsgbox
from .models import Todo
from .forms import Post
# Create your views here.


def list_todo_items(request):
    context = {
        'todo_list' : Todo.objects.all(),
        'count': Todo.objects.count()
    }
    # count = Todo.objects.count()
    # context2 = {'count': count}
    # context = {'count': Todo.objects.count()}
    # count = Todo.objects.count()
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def insert_todo_item(request: HttpRequest):
    todo = Todo(content=request.POST['content'])
    try:
        todo.full_clean()

    except ValidationError:
        # pymsgbox.alert('ValidationError! Phone number must be entered in the format: +999999999. Up to 15 digits allowed.', 'Title')
        return redirect('/main/list/')

    todo.save()
    return redirect('/main/list/')

def delete_todo_item(request,todo_id):
    todo_to_delete = Todo.objects.get(id=todo_id)
    todo_to_delete.delete()
    return redirect('/main/list/')
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'MyDB',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'postgres',
        # 'HOST':'XXXXXX.postgres.pythonanywhere-services.com',
        # 'PORT': '11111'
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Have you setup a Twilio account and looked at their quickstart? They have great Python examples on sending SMS messages: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/python

Comment: @MaestroFJP I have set up my twilio account and I've sent messages using a csv before, I have my app storing things on a local postgres database, but I just can't figure out how to send sms to those numbers stored as records in the database. For example, every time a user enters their number in my app, a new record is added to the DB and once that happens I'd like for that number they inputted to receive a text

Comment: @MaestroFJP I can't find any good examples of integration between twilio and a local app using postgres, I came across Zapier, but it says that my database has to reside some place that isn't localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: It would be helpful to add some code of how what your Django models look like.

Comment: @MaestroFJP okay I will add that! Thank you

Comment: @MaestroFJP I've added the code from my models, views and settings to show how the database is being used

Comment: @MaestroFJP perhaps I'm thinking of it wrong, and don't need to consult the DB at all, would it be better to just broadcast the message to each new entry in the insert_todo_item view?

Comment: Yes, I was going to suggest making an API call to Twilio in the `insert_todo_item` view. The data resides in the PGSQL, but it's not going to make the call to Twilio as you'll want to do that in your Django application.